# ruby watir browser.send_keys times out after 60 seconds if machine unattended

Tags: ruby, windows, focus, watir, sendkeys

I'm working with send_keys where I have to hit Enter

```
@ie.element(:css, "#accountSwitcherSelect.dijitDownArrowButton").send_keys :enter
```

which makes another object that switches accounts visible

```
@ie.div(:id => "accountSwitcherSelect_dropdown").table(:id => "accountSwitcherSelect_menu")
```

Here's the kicker, it works perfectly if I'm there, and the browser is in focus in the foreground.

But, if I either 
a) lock the Windows OS screen, or 
b) are working on a Remote Desktop and switch out of RDP, or 
c) started running the ruby script from a scheduled task on an unattended machine 
it will see the first dropdown just fine

```
puts @ie.element(:css, "#accountSwitcherSelect.dijitDownArrowButton").visible?
```

but it never does   *send_keys :enter*   and never will see  *"accountSwitcherSelect_menu"* and throws

> timed out after 60 seconds

error

watir 6.10.3, ruby 2.2.5, Windows OS, IE 11

--Here's the full error message, where line 125 is

```
@ie.element(:css, "#accountSwitcherSelect.dijitDownArrowButton").send_keys :enter
```

> C:/ruby225/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rautomation-0.17.0/lib/rautomation/wait_helper.rb:20:in
>   `wait_until': timed out  after 60 seconds
>   (RAutomation::WaitHelper::TimeoutError)
>           from C:/ruby225/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rautomation-0.17.0/lib/rautomation/adapter/win_32/window.rb:153:in`
>   block in send_keys'
>           from C:/ruby225/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rautomation-0.17.0/lib/rautomation/adapter/win_32/window.rb:152:in
>   `each'
>           from C:/ruby225/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rautomation-0.17.0/lib/rautomation/adapter/win_32/window.rb:152:in`
>   send_keys'
>           from C:/ruby225/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rautomation-0.17.0/lib/rautomation/window.rb:192:in
>   `send_keys'
>           from C:/ruby225/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/watir-classic-4.3.0/lib/watir-classic/browser.rb:452:in`
>   send_keys '
>           from C:/ruby225/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/watir-classic-4.3.0/lib/watir-classic/element.rb:124:in
>   `send_keys '
>           from DeleteTriggers8.rb:125:in`block in '
>           from DeleteTriggers8.rb:106:in `each'
>           from DeleteTriggers8.rb:106:in`'

Comment: Kindly paste the whole error message

Comment: "timed out after 60 seconds" is the whole error message I get when doing begin rescue Exception => e
  puts "\nException caught as of #{Time.now}: #{e}"

Comment: No remove the rescue block and run the program and get the whole message and update  it in the question..

Comment: Are you using WATIR(Powered by Selenium) Or WATIR -classic? Because `rautomation-0.17.0/` is in watir-classic which has already been deprecated.

Comment: Thank you @Rajagopalan the browser window focus issue seemed to be a limitation of  now deprecated watir-classic.  Switching to later watir-webdriver solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Rajagopalan the browser window focus issue seemed to be a limitation of now deprecated watir-classic. Switching to latest watir-webdriver solves the problem.

Comment: Okay, no problem

Comment: Note that watir-webdriver is also deprecated and you should be using just plain "watir" and make sure it is version 6+

Comment: Right, @titusfortner, I uninstalled watir-classic, commonwatir, watir-webdriver, installed watir 6.10.3, and are doing require 'watir'  Does that sound right?

Comment: Yup, just wanted to make sure you were getting the latest and greatest. :)